# DB2Driver.changeDB2Password returns invalid URL when password is 15 characters

Tags: jdbc, db2

I created a java tool using DB2Driver.changeDB2Password and it works successfully when the zOS password is 8 characters long.  However, our zOS system implemented a minimum 15 character passphrase that users are switching to and when we attempt to use the tool to change a 15 character password, we get the following error:

```
Invalid database URL syntax: jdbc:db2://meuba.vipa.uk.ibm.com:446/EUBADB2A:retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
```

Code:

```
DB2Driver.changeDB2Password(url, user, new String(pwd), new String(newPwd));
```

URL:  jdbc:db2://iccmvs2.pok.ibm.com:6009/DSN:retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage=true

Change the URL to 'jdbc:db2://iccmvs2.pok.ibm.com:6009' and it's successful.  However, our new password phrase length is min 15 .. max 100 characters.

I can't find any documentation on the URL length. What's the URL length? or did I find a bug?

db2jcc4.jar : v11.1 : IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ 4.24.92

Comment: When you run the java program, are you connecting __DIRECTLY__ to the Db2-for-Z/os subsystem, or are you connecting __via__ a gateway (e.g Db2-connect)?

Comment: Also, are you able to change the password correctly with the Db2 CLP (i.e. not using java) ? The docs suggest that the max password length for data sources is 32 bytes.

Comment: Users are issue direct JDBC from local machine to zOS.  No gateway .. but possible firewalls. I don't think password length is the issue, yet.  Currently, I don't know of anyone that has password length > 32 bytes.  Most are probably sticking to >15 + few characters.  
We have a complete mix of users changing passwords using QMF , DB2 CLP, native zOS host login.  This Java tool is for those two don't have those three already available for them to use.   And I can change a 15 length password if I use the shorter URL.

Comment: The sqlcode -4461 suggests it is the Db2-subsystem that is rejecting something. Suggest you take a jdbc-trace (refer to the Db2 Knowledge Centre) for instructions, and then study the output, and engage IBM Db2 Support for assistance with the troubleshooting.  You could also eliminate the v11.1fp3 db2jcc4.jar by using the latest build shipped with V11.5.4 downloadable from fix central.

Comment: thanks,  I'll run jdbc-trace, review and report back.

Comment: It is worthwhile to try the __latest__ jdbc driver (for v11.5.4 from fix central) before doing a jdbc trace